# Integration in complex analysis using Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Prove that for $a>0$, 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4+a^4}dx=\frac{\pi}{a^3\sqrt{2}}
$$
I think I'm supposed to use Cauchy's Residue Theorem somehow, but I don't know what closed path to use or even where to begin really! Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use the interval [-b,b], followed by a half-circle from [b,0] to [-b,0]. Let b tend to infinity, then the integral over the half-circle tends to 0.

Comment: would we have a simple pole at x=-a, and is that the only singularity?

Comment: How many complex roots has a complex polynomial of degree $4$?

Comment: There are no real poles because $x^4+a^4$ is always positive, as a>0. All the poles are complex with nonzero imaginary part.

Answer (score 5):

Define $C$ by a quarter-circle of radius $R$ in the first quadrant.  Then consider

$$\oint_C \frac{dz}{z^4+a^4} = \int_0^R \frac{dx}{x^4+a^4} + i R \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{1}{R^4 e^{i 4 \theta}+a^4}+i\int_R^0 \frac{dy}{y^4+a^4}$$

Note that in the third integral, I used the fact that $i^4=1$.  Now consider the limit as $R \to \infty$; the second integral vanishes in this limit.  This is because that integral has a magnitude bounded by

$$\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{R}{R^4-a^4}$$

which clearly vanishes as $R\to\infty$.  Thus, in this limit, the contour integral is

$$(1-i) \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^4+a^4}$$

The contour integral is also, by the residue theorem, equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at the pole $z=a e^{i \pi/4}$.  Thus,

$$\sqrt{2} e^{-i \pi/4} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^4+a^4} = i 2 \pi \frac{1}{4 a^3 e^{i 3 \pi/4}}$$

or

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^4+a^4} = \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2} a^3}$$

The integral over the entire real line is twice this, as expected.